What could be causing Gradle to fail to resolve these dependencies?
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.6.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2.
     Required by:
         project :app


//
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Do not place your application dependencies here.
        // They belong in the individual module build.gradle files.

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        google()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Checked Repository Configuration:
I added repositories like google(), mavenCentral(), and maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in my build.gradle file to ensure the dependencies are accessible.
Disabled Offline Mode:
I made sure that Gradle's offline mode was turned off to allow it to fetch dependencies from the internet.
Cleared Gradle Cache:
I deleted the .gradle folder in both the project’s root directory and in my user’s home directory to remove any potentially corrupted cache files.
Verified Dependency Versions:
I checked the versions of the dependencies com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.0, com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.6, and us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2 to ensure they are correctly specified and should be available.
Synced Project with Gradle Files:
I clicked on "Sync Project with Gradle Files" in Android Studio after making the above changes.
What I expected:
Gradle to resolve and download the dependencies successfully, allowing the build to complete without errors.
but nothing work

Your gradle file tells that you might be using very old version of android studio. First thing you should do is to update it.
I added your dependencies in my build.gradle (App level) dependencies section and it successfully downloaded them.
